# Can anyone interpret the data in this UDP packet?

Tags: networking, virus, wireshark

I have been receiving large amounts of traffic to my computer recently so I downloaded and ran wireshark to find out I have been receiving lots of UDP packets.
All of the packets I have received are identical and both the source and destination address cannot be ping-ed.

--Packet info--

Source Address: 10.239.1.17

Destination Address: 239.200.20.114

Source Port: 47811

Destination Port: 10000

My private address is 192.168.1.13.
Below is the data of one of the thousand packets I have received in 1 second

8021cc65ea7de781749c70464700221974be7362b02ea725f3876f0facc2a493754314dac2d339b6762ea769daccce9c65d462daecaff8cf696620600db6538dfe7417aacc82e71e626ac17221e976f6b263fd365db49f9c94d080508d6b2b8f619d9f5701bb4334fb85255b4e22efcc13fb269dab67831b96cdd0893942af8517d758daa1fc673fe029fe123c2760d074b3e963a3ec720c825f0e1ca15377c6056b24aa934a81a39a4f2aa3684d61f6a967ddfe6e5dc793f935dfb73c86e33b128bd50da40aab174700221a0b277bcaafc28552cf76c9c56709d975d76ba4f5c26cc5122f281913cc820e928d58e40823c3db4dbcca70d94d5f6873e82d2344d346f1e54c2372abe14fffcec73cb89dddd06175faae18515c15a8f1dbc131c4e3049bd8ef64c2e2e44d7ea303f0338811b2acc6ee1e8148852699e2499b66fb43f2bc7c6df1d518e32eadc617887a30e205398b7cb32509ac580d4c43738943970470559f02c2f76ca7da7cc38d8873682fad8a6da5627396149f07432b44b9eb1cabb74700221b4ce287b1bd0fb5ef5fb0943b13a3e84ccb0eab61051e867092c347cfae98bfac1ee38291052168285d8a4997bdae8f467a10e47e24cd501a45a9f3524f4861ccf33267aeecd2660210e6740d6c155b33f8733d4d3f8d237f363adaa951c64997369f488c12bb161d5c8b646138c7e53bc05f9b1f70fe992677bac1ea3a8978c0feb44f511b7a29c3af277248817f691613534c08d223b623935b873da3d12bc69f11203b3c5ba7869f9880b51ea284ee06daabc900a134384700221c2822aa2953936b4e64f8a9ed3090a01a9d7fe3b09f2d7c4333a2c17213e9e114c6f5a1b88122f76e642e72039eb35ffc8cc937cd0124610e5403d0271af0b2d3096da1004ca0c419054141b1b8599e13cb99edc19546125803a700ad43eae188ae3a4359e84f4a8cbc023a6ae7cd4fa27e8e44bdb529b835eece9e17b55a3d69f92e1657df5797f8c02a39c367f595087d7cc950bc4ca1b8c94aa318a3882ffa3769d1848e98af95aab1f4071fb273ba94d54f488d487b314700221d9865f661f7bc70af60df1a63b0437127054b609921f719f81beb3b143435c912d139d5161c0b59980a36719ef29dc195f7c4e8b3bc03bfd57b160ec03b9668bb57318b2495d6ab6aab4229ea40826660a1285ce3b9c8f069e336c6f72d3ff0a2893919d57af7f9f98305468550ee30e3385fd05de4b7ea0b40ac6b689a424054f4e75a0a75ecbe5a4a57031976f5f54d73a38bda44617227882de077662ea75209b2812fc9ef178ef42e75251f758792416679c725c02ed64700221ec8d5a2649e0f587023e7bca5499e4e594b515e269c1435071ceab0c030e58d20cb9810c12cc97c88bc2045014fa8321ed763220b2f3076f6885198ec61fade1ccd00e8d1c557472c15d7a94d1b259f85f0190ccf0711be8d9165cb2cb97f729f643d127f8a1a7ab3d2fb32364d6a9769202219b43ce51fd139ad880880150c2f5569513d712d445a5a1daf3239fac76ff6174dc57e28d2281caabf8d748bbfab3949227d35ddf5208c842768c6ea4742b3aa9016b2bc965c4700221fe6d2cdf9423c8c305ebf4cc7494937ee78e8ecd2670b1efe4a6468e83a2143ad8524eb5c5e5d038039087ae8a567b3d44772a3559149d0242e58cfdd5fdf5ec82f64c12e2d28a499ff919b43e1266c1bc0409134a849e93ff1a179529b30bc463bc24c328ba52cf377cb73b0efd512bb52a901aa1a05434496aa0d85a5ed934d9c3865bba141fa945ee64a3ab801c6a65120d7758180eeff25d3ff5340ba607aa41f1796ef564858f0a2b2797689b751c0877df717a9e48d

Comment: It's multicast. Probably IPTV.

Comment: @DanielB Why don't you put that in an answer and elaborate a bit *how you know*? Even if the answer isn't perfect, it's a step in the right direction and might give hints to others knowing more.

Comment: @Mario Because I'm on my phone now with a super low bandwidth connection. ;)

Comment: @DanielB Yes I have confirmed that it was an IPTV that shared a switch with me. Thank you!
Now how do I block that multicast stream?

Answer (score 1):

So, well, as to the how and why.

The destination address, `239.200.20.114`, is within the so-called [Administratively Scoped IPv4 Multicast address range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Administratively_Scoped_IPv4_Multicast_addresses). That means it wasn’t routed over the internet, but locally from your ISP.

The destination port, `10000`, is a known multicast IPTV port. I know it’s used with Microsoft’s IPTV platform because I once subscribed to Telekom Entertain, a German IPTV service.

In your local network, multicast traffic essentially becomes broadcast traffic. That’s why everyone is receiving it. Going from my experience, your devices would use [IGMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) to request the router pass through a multicast stream. After stopping playback, a device should once again use IGMP to signal the router that passing through the stream is no longer required. There may be various reasons as to why it doesn’t do that or your router may simply be malfunctioning.

Switches sometimes have a feature called [IGMP Snooping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGMP_snooping) that looks for IGMP messages and forwards traffic to its ports accordingly, instead of forwarding it to all ports (so-called flooding).

So, basically, you can’t do that much about it. Maybe reboot your router. Still, it’s totally not a security issue.